# inserting an integer into a sorted list

Tags: list, prolog

So my problem is this i have a predicate called insere_ordenado(El,Lst1,Lst2) in which El is a random integer, Lst1 is a list and Lst2 is the resulting list of adding El to Lst1.

The thing is i did this recursively but now i have to do this iteratively and the problem is when i want to add a number that is bigger or equal than the biggest number of the list it doesnt add anything.

Example:

```
?- insere_ordenado_ite(2,[1,2,3,6,9],L2).
L2 = [1, 2, 2, 3, 6, 9].

?- insere_ordenado_ite(5,[1,2,3,6,9],L2).
L2 = [1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 9].

?- insere_ordenado_ite(0,[1,2,3,6,9],L2).
L2 = [0, 1, 2, 3, 6, 9].

?- insere_ordenado_ite(9,[1,2,3,6,9],L2).
L2 = [1, 2, 3, 6, 9] .

?- insere_ordenado_ite(10,[1,2,3,6,9],L2).
L2 = [1, 2, 3, 6, 9] .
```

As you can see in the example that i want to add 9 or 10 its supposed to add 9 or 10 (depending on the example) at the end.

Program:

```
insere_ordenado_ite(El,L1,L2) :-  insere_ordenado_ite(El,L1,L2,[]).

insere_ordenado_ite(El,[],L2,L2).

insere_ordenado_ite(El,[P|R],L2,AC) :- El >= P,
                                       append(AC,[P],NAC),
                                       insere_ordenado_ite(El,R,L2,NAC).

insere_ordenado_ite(El,[P|R],L2,AC) :- El < P,
                                       append(AC,[El,P],NAC),
                                       append(NAC,R,NNAC),
                                       insere_ordenado_ite(El,[],L2,NNAC).
```

I think the problem is that something is missing from the stop condition, but I'm not sure what it is or how to do it exactly, honestly any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean by random? You probably wanted to say arbitrary

Comment: Yes i typed it wrong it just inserting an integer into a sorted list

Comment: I suppose "iteratively" means that no actions have to be performed after the recursive call, which would make the procedure subject to tail-call optimization, unless something peculiar happens in the pattern matching part of the head (haven't figured out when that is the case). But using append is cheating. You need to use a "difference list" (list with a tail that is a fresh variable)...

Answer (score 0):

How about this, which I happen to have on hand.

It's as iterative as possible, there is nothing which happens after an `insert_help/3`, call. The tail of the difflist is constrained to a valid list eventually, and as variables are really global, this fact is immediately visible to whoever shares the variable, in this case `insert/3`.

```
insert(P,List,T) :-
   DiffList=[-1|T]-T, % -1 is a guard, smaller than anything, removed later
   insert_help(P,List,DiffList).   

insert_help(P,[Px|R],H-T) :-
    P>Px,!,
    format("go right at ~q into ~q, difflist: ~q\n",[P,[Px|R],H-T]),
    T=[Px|TT],
    insert_help(P,R,H-TT).

insert_help(P,[P|R],H-T) :-
    !,
    format("~q exists in ~q, difflist: ~q\n",[P,[P|R],H-T]),
    T=[P|R].

insert_help(P,[Px|R],H-T) :-
    P<Px,!,
    format("insert-before at ~q into ~q, difflist: ~q\n",[P,[Px|R],H-T]),
    T=[P,Px|R].

insert_help(P,[],H-T) :-
    !,
    format("insert ~q at end, difflist: ~q\n",[P,H-T]),
    T=[P].

:-begin_tests(inserting).

test(1) :- insert(10,[],R),R=[10].
test(2) :- insert(11,[2,3,5,7],R),R=[2,3,5,7,11].
test(3) :- insert(2,[3,5,7,11],R),R=[2,3,5,7,11].
test(4) :- insert(3,[2,3,5,7,11],R),R=[2,3,5,7,11].
test(5) :- insert(3,[2,5,7,11],R),R=[2,3,5,7,11].
test(6) :- insert(7,[2,3,5,11],R),R=[2,3,5,7,11].
test(7) :- insert(2,[],R),R=[2].

:-end_tests(inserting).

rt :- run_tests(inserting).
```

## Addendum: Solving it with `append/{2,3}`

If you have `append/3` (and `append/2`), you can just do:

```
insert_with_append(El,List,Out) :-
   search(El,List,0,Result),
   ((Result >= 0)                       % -1 means entry exists
    ->
       (length(Front,Result),           % create list of fresh variables of length Result
        append(Front,Back,List),        % rip list apart into Front, Back
        append([Front,[El],Back],Out))  % build result
    ;
       Out = List % already exists in list
    ).

% search/4 looks for the insert position, counting the number of 
% items in List that come before Element, and setting CounterOut
% to that value, once known. CounterOut is set to -1 if Element
% is already in the list.

% search(Element,List,CounterCur,CounterOut)

search(_,[],Counter,Counter) :- !.

search(E,[L|Ls],CounterCur,CounterOut) :-
   L<E,!,
   succ(CounterCur,CounterNext),
   search(E,Ls,CounterNext,CounterOut).

search(E,[L|_],CounterCur,CounterCur) :-
   E<L,!.

search(E,[E|_],_,-1). 


:-begin_tests(insert_with_append).

test(1) :- insert_with_append(10,[],R),R=[10].
test(2) :- insert_with_append(11,[2,3,5,7],R),R=[2,3,5,7,11].
test(3) :- insert_with_append(2,[3,5,7,11],R),R=[2,3,5,7,11].
test(4) :- insert_with_append(3,[2,3,5,7,11],R),R=[2,3,5,7,11].
test(5) :- insert_with_append(3,[2,5,7,11],R),R=[2,3,5,7,11].
test(6) :- insert_with_append(7,[2,3,5,11],R),R=[2,3,5,7,11].
test(7) :- insert_with_append(2,[],R),R=[2].

:-end_tests(insert_with_append).

rt :- run_tests(insert_with_append).
```

Comment: and how is append cheating i am clearly not doing any recursion besides the last call

Comment: A difflist ("difference list", which would better be called "list difference") is a list which has a tail that is still a variable: `[1,2,3|T]-T` As you know the variable `T`, you can use it as a reference to the tail of the list and "append" efficiently. See above code.

Comment: @MartimCorreia Well, append is super-powerful, isn't it like saying "I didn't use a gun" when you blew the whole appartment complex apart with a JDAM?

Comment: @MartimCorreia Must-read: "Difference Lists" by Frank Pfenning: https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~fp/courses/lp/lectures/11-diff.pdf

Comment: Well for some reason append is allowed, but yeah i get ya